# Remove inner list element based on condition using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, list

Remove inner list element based on condition using lambda expression. I have achieved it through foreach. Need to implement using lambda expression or Linq

Please help

```
if (!FwContext.User.UserRoles.Exists(s => s.RoleCd == "Admin"))
{
    foreach (var item in items.ToList())
    {
        foreach (var attribute in item.ItemAttributeValues.ToList())
        {
            if (attribute.AttributeNm == "EST" && attribute.StatusNm == "SAP")
            {
                 item.ItemAttributeValues.Remove(attribute);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: Is this home work? If you need to do out with a lambda expression or linq, why do you use a foreach loop?

Comment: we can modify a collection if we use .ToList() and  the above code is working fine with out any error.

Comment: @MongZhu i was not asked to do using lamda , later they changed their mind.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace RemoveItemFromListWithLinq_42565975
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoIt();
        }

        private static void DoIt()
        {
            List<string> thelist = new List<string>() { "file1", "file2", "file3" };
            thelist = thelist.Where(p => p != "file2").ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", thelist));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Using attributes like your opening post

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace RemoveItemFromListWithLinq_42565975
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoIt();
        }

        private static void DoIt()
        {
            List<string> thelist = new List<string>() { "file1", "file2", "file3" };
            thelist = thelist.Where(p => p.Length == 5 && p != "file2" ).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", thelist));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This wont work. I have to remove the element from inner list . My issue is with list with in another list.

Comment: Item is one list and ItemattributeValues is another list with in item

Answer (score 0):

Currently what I found is  below. And it is working fine.

```
items.ToList().ForEach(item =>
                    {
                    var attr = item.ItemAttributeValues.ToList().Where(x => x.AttributeNm == "EST" && x.StatusNm == "SAP").FirstOrDefault();
                    item.ItemAttributeValues.Remove(attr);
                    }
                );
```

please tell if we can do it in better way.

Comment: if you want to add information to your post please use the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42565975/edit) below your post. Please don't post additional information as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
items.ToList().ForEach(item => item.ItemAttributeValues.Remove(item.ItemAttributeValues.ToList().ToList().Where(x => x.AttributeNm == "EST_DIE_SZ_AREA" && x.StatusNm == "SAP Adopted").FirstOrDefault()));
```

Gave the query a small modification

Comment: if you want to add information to your post please use the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42565975/edit) below your post. Please don't post additional information as answer.